# Error when running jar file using JavaFX dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar

I need to create a jar file with dependencies so that I can transfer it without the source code files. But when you launch such a jar by double-clicking, nothing works, but if you run it through the command line in the java -jar file.jar format, the following error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at uip.gui.JavaFxRun.<clinit>(JavaFxRun.java:16)
        ... 8 more
```

Here is my code with plugin and launch code:

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
     <execution>
      <goals>
       <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
    <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
    <mainClass>
     uip.gui.JavaFxRun
    </mainClass>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
   </executions>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

File with JavaFX:

```
public class JavaFXClassFrame extends Application {

    static Logger LOGGER;

    static {
        try (FileInputStream ins = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/log.config")) {
            LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(ins);
            LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(JavaFXClassFrame.class.getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Error ", e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            URL xmlUrl = getClass().getResource("/fileFxml.fxml");
            loader.setLocation(xmlUrl);
            Parent root = loader.load();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Success ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error", e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class JavaFxRun {
    static Logger LOGGER;

    static {
        try (FileInputStream ins = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/log.config")) {
            LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(ins);
            LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(JavaFxRun.class.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Error ", e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaFXClassFrame.main(args);
    }
}
```

JavaFX launch file:

```
public class JavaFxRun {
    static Logger LOGGER;

    static {
        try (FileInputStream ins = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/log.config")) {
            LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(ins);
            LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(JavaFxRun.class.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Error ", e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaFXClassFrame.main(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [the stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors), the problem is caused by line 16 of `JavaFxRun` but there is also a previous problem in this line:

```
try (FileInputStream ins = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/log.config")) {
```

The `FileInputStream` reads a file from the file system, not from the JAR; furthermore, if you unpack the JAR, you'll see that the path of `log.config` is not the one you have specified.

Try to replace that line with

```
try (InputStream ins = JavaFxRun.class.getResourceAsStream("/log.config")) {
```

This line uses the method [`getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) of the `Class` object representing the class `JavaFxRun`.

Comment: Yes ... but this doesn't fix the entire problem.  See my answer.

Comment: I used your hint and it didn't help :(

Comment: @ZabbixJs, "it didn't help" doesn't say much: have you got a different stack trace?  That line is certainly wrong.  Have you replaced the `LOGGER.log` call as suggested by Stephen?  Is `log.config` the right name of the file?  What is its content?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are getting an **uncaught** `NullPointerException` somewhere in this code:

```
static Logger LOGGER;

static {
    try (FileInputStream ins = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/log.config")) {
        LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(ins);
        LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(JavaFxRun.class.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Error ", e);
    }
}
```

It is a bit tricky to work out which exact line this is happening on (i.e. which line is line 16 of JavaFxRun.java) but think that the problem is this line:

```
     LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Error ", e);
```

As far as I can tell, that is the *only* line that *could* throw an NPE.  Here's how it happens:

1. You attempt to open "src/main/resources/log.config".
2. That throws a `FileNotFoundException` because (presumably) that file is not at the expected file system location *when application is run outside of your IDE*.
3. The FNFE is caught by your `catch (Exception e) {...}`
4. You attempt call a method via the `LOGGER` variables ... and NPE.

The NPE happens because `LOGGER` didn't get initialized.  And that happens because the FNFE was thrown and caught *before the body of the `try` statement was executed*.

Basically, you can't use the logging system to log that you couldn't configure the logging system.  The best you can do is to write the error message directly to *standard error* and hope that it goes somewhere useful.

Note: replacing `new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/log.config")` with something that can actually find the file (or a resource) will cure the FNFE that triggered the NPE in this case.  But that's not the end of it.  What if (say) the resource is missing?  What it the file or resource is found, but it contains an garbled logging configuration.  **You will still get the NPE!**

Basically, the `LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Error ", e);` statement is wrong.  It won't ever work as you intend.  If you get to that line and try to use `LOGGER`, an NPE is inevitable.

Comment: How can I fix the error then?

Comment: That is, what do I need to change in the code or in the maven settings for everything to work?

Comment: I think I've answered that already.  1) Replace the `LOGGER.log` call with a code to print the stacktrace to stderr.  2) Read **that** stacktrace to confirm that the root cause is a missing file.  3) Remedy the missing file problem; see @Pino's answer.  Hint: if you are going to use resource loading, check that the "log.config" file has been included in the JAR file in the correct place.  The `getResourceAsStream()` method will return `null` if it can't find the resource ... and that could trigger an NPE too.

Comment: I should point out that the onus is on >you< to learn / understand the Java language, read /understand the respective javadocs, and read / understand the docs for Maven, Spring-boot and so on.  Relying on other people to diagnose your problems and spoon-feed you instructions on how to fix them doesn't scale.